# How to open a separate activity on button press?

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity, main-activity

I want a button to open an activity class that sets a layout xml file. Everything is in order but the button doesn't work without the @Override method. With the @Override method I get this error:

> The method onCreate1(Bundle) of type MainActivity must override or
>   implement a supertype method.

```
    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from activity_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Locate the button in activity_main.xml
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MyButton);

        // Capture button clicks
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // Start NewActivity.class
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        NewActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
    }
```

The reason is I already have an @Override annotation for another method.

What I have tried:

- Reading the tutorial on activities, multiple activities, and passing data between activities.
- Solving the problem by editing the android manifest.
- Creating a separate launch intent for the activity.

Comment: Why is your method named `onCreate1`?

Comment: What exactly you want to do on button pressed?

Comment: You either need more practice in object oriented languages with regards to inheritance and polymorphism or you need to understand Android's Activity life cycle more clearly.
Your question is very vague and can't be understood. Please make sure to clarify what you want and don't understand exactly.

Comment: You **can't** override a **non existing** Android method. Remove the `@Override` from onCreate1(), and call your method from within another one (possibly acll it at the end of your onCreate() method).

Comment: Why can't I just @Override the main method above this method?

Comment: You can only override **real** Android methods. And **onCreate1()** is NOT.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use method with name onCreate1(), you need to remove `@Override` from it

Comment: Then the button does nothing. It doesn't open the other activity. The method becomes useless.

Comment: @officialasim Why don't you remove this method then and use onCreate() method

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
@Override
public void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

to

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call it the same as the function you want to Override.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    somethingSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed the @Override annotation as suggested. Renamed the onCreate1 method to onCreate. I want this question closed as well because I need to think further upon how to effectively solve this problem.